# "UnConsting" const value via pointer

Tags: c++

First, sorry for possible question redundancy.

Doing some little experiments with C/C++ pointers in GCC I encountered this somewhat weird behaviour when bypassing constantness of value at the pointer address.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    const double number = 100;
//bypassing constantess of pointed-to value
    double * pointer_to_value = (double *) &number;
    *pointer_to_value += 200;

    cout << "Adress of number: " << &number << "\tValue of number: " << number << endl <<
    "   Pointer value: " << pointer_to_value << "\tDereferencing pointer: " << *pointer_to_value;

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect both form of checking the value yielding same results. Location of value is same in both cases. Program generates following output, however:

*Adress of number: 0x22ff30 Value of number: **100**
Pointer value: 0x22ff30 Dereferencing pointer: **300***

Anyone capable of explaining?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check it out this -> "http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5508"

Comment: compile-time optimizations perhaps?

Comment: @mandy - link should be http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5508 (without the quotes)

Comment: you should use static_cast and dynamic_cast in c++. not the C cast operator as you did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing const value in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709548/changing-const-value-in-c)

Comment: @Stephane: `const_cast` in this case.

Comment: @Mike, no, static_cast<> in this case, which would have output a logically a compilation error since this code is a purely a bug in itself, or a dynamic_cast<> that would have safely returned a null pointer. On the contrarty, const_cast<> should be use only in rare rare times when one know that there is a non-const variable hidden behind... Promoting the use of const_cast is really not a good thing unless one really knows what is going behind. Obviously not the case here, since the compiler may really do what it wants with a const double declared on the heap.

Answer (score 10):

It's [undefined behaivor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

It's irrelevant why exactly it happens (actually because the compiler inlines the value).

Answer (score 5):

`"UnConsting” const value via pointer` is a ***Undefined Behavior***.
So it is not posible to define a behavior not defined by the Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler optimization. Compiler doesn't expect you to try and trick it like that, it knows that the value is `const`, so it just cached it. Try to compile it without any optimization, and see if it makes any difference.

Generally the meaning of `const` is:

> constant - the object shall not be modified. Attempt to do so results in undefined behavior. On most of the compilers it is compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler optimization. You can overcome that by adding `volatile` keyword to the variable.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    volatile const double number = 100;
    //bypassing constantess of pointed-to value
    double * pointer_to_value = (double *) &number;
    *pointer_to_value += 200;

    cout << "Adress of number: " << &number << "\tValue of number: " << number << endl <<
    "   Pointer value: " << pointer_to_value << "\tDereferencing pointer: " << *pointer_to_value;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually the way to overcome this problem is by not invoking undefined behavior in the first place. Like not trying to modify data that's originally `const`.

Comment: It's still undefined behavior. The compiler can put `number` into a read-only memory.

Comment: Very well agreed, one shouldn't even think of doing this. But this actually solves what (s)he *expected*.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that gcc has done some optimizations on your behalf, replacing the reference to `<< number` with `<< 100`. Should be possible to verify by looking at the generated asm code.